# Can't import {Text} from React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been looking for a way to add inline text with different styles. [I found this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#nested-text) and tried to import it.

```js
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

import { styles } from './styles.js';


class App extends Component {

}
```

However, I got the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed `react-native`? check your `package.json` and run `npm install`

Comment: @Calvin I have

    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"

Sorry, I'm new to this. I ran npm install, what should I do next to install react-native?

Comment: this might be silly to ask but u ran npm install  inside newportfolio folder right ? and package.json is located in the same folder as well right ?

Comment: @Avinash yes, I did. It did install react-native, most specifically "react-native": "^0.55.4",

Comment: did you run npm install -g create-react-native-app or npm install -g create-react-app ?
because you didn't find  react-native in package.json earlier

Comment: @Avinash initially I installed create-react-app. Now I added native. The reason for native is to get this { Text }. However, is it possible to do it through create-react-app?

Comment: `create-react-app` is for React web project. Which one are you going for? React Native project or React project?

Comment: I guess you installed create-react-app and then react-native by npm install react-native, (which won't work) because create-react-native-app sets up a lot of things
you better install create-react-native-app and start from scratch again

Comment: @Calvin a web project!

Comment: @Avinash oh, I see! But there isn't a way to get the inline { Text } with the create-react-app?

Comment: if you are planning to build a web app then no need to use Text you can use div tags or any html tags, no need fo react-native here, 
if you want to build cross platform mobile apps for ios or  android then you need to use react-native and its components like Text
(Ofcourse you can create your own Text component and use it in your react web app but thats not what you're looking for)

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm i react-native` to install react-native in your `package.json` directory. Or you can follow the Getting Started guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html using `create-react-native-app` to start a working project.

Comment: It did install it indeed, however the error persists.

Comment: Are you using the exact same import code? `import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';` from the Text example.

Comment: Yes, the same exact code. For clarity, now I have on my dependencies "react-native": "^0.55.4",